# Реализация слайдера на Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, owl-carousel

Всем привет, у меня вопрос, какие идеи по реализации Слайдер на Wordpress существуют.
Заказчик попросил реализовать слайдер на главной странице.

**На сайте используется всего 2 плагина:**

1. WP Multilang
2. ACF - PRO

На фронте использую Owl Carousel внутри карусели есть 4 Item(Карточка слайдера, SLIDE)
Можно прописать новые поля в ACF но тогда пользователь будет ограничен только 4мя слайдами

**Задача заключается в следующем:**

В Item(Карточка слайдера, SLIDE) карусели есть:

- IMG
- POST NAME
- POST TEXT

Возможен ли вариант реализовать эту карусель, через ACF но реализовать это так, чтоб администратор мог добавлять ITEM (Карточка слайдера, SLIDE), если ему нужно больше чем 4 Слайда ?

```
<div class="owl-item">
    <a class="card card_type_0" href="#">
        <div class="card__container">
            <div class="card__image" style="URL">
                <img src="URL" class="img-fluid d-none wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy">
            </div>
            <div class="card__content">
                <div class="card__post_container">
                    <div class="card__post_name">
                        POST NAME
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__post_text">
                        <p>
                        POST TEXT
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Почему четырьмя? С какой стати. Полей acf может быть любое количество. Учите циклы в php.

Comment: Да полей может быть сколько угодно, согласен, но только к примеру я делаю 4 поля для Айтэмов, Администратор 4 и заполнит, а как сделать так чтоб он мог добавлять эти поля в режиме редактирования страницы?

Comment: Repeater в ACF Pro

Comment: Странно но у меня нет типа поля Repeater (Повторитель) в выборе ACF но в настройках плагина написано что это ПРО версия,